# make dropdown list without the dropdown are pushing the left or right content down (the other links around it)?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have tried without success to make a dropdown list without the content are getting pushed down under the dropdown, i can't get it to work, i have tried with float and display wont work :s 
Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: check it out here http://codepen.io/o0nico0o/pen/LEqoKx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really doesn't seem like you have come a long way at all, so I'd be hesitant to just write a long answer to explain how dropdowns work, and instead suggest that you look up tutorials. You are probably going to need to use javascript to make the dropdown "clickable" to open and close it.

But I'll try to start you off in the right direction!

To avoid making the dropdown move other elements, it needs to have the css attribute "position:absolute;" and the parent element (the element the menu is inside) has to have the attribute "position:relative;"

```
<style>
    .menuButton{
        position:relative;
    }

    .dropDown{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
    }
</style>

<div class="menuButton"> 
    <p>Click me!</p>
    <div class="dropDown">
        <ul>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Though further, I'd suggest you use javascript to toggle the ".dropDown" class' attribute "display:none" on and off. You will most likely learn better by googling, because I dont think I have teach you, and people are probably not going to give you a lot of help here on such a basic question